# How to write 'if' statement for free / paid productFlavors?

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, android-productflavors

Wanting to learn how to publish free and paid versions of my app, I made a simple app in which the 'paid' version has an ImageView which opens a second Activity when clicked, and the 'free' version doesn't have this ImageView so can't open the second Activity. I have set up 'free' and 'paid' ProductFlavors and made 'free' and 'paid' source sets, each with a 'res' folder and a 'layout' folder containing a version of activity_main.xml. In the paid sourceset the xml file is identical to that in the 'main' source set (perhaps this is redundant), but the xml in the free sourceset doesn't include this image (I imagine that in my real app I'll create layout file versions which include or don't include Adviews). I have an 'if' statement in MainActivity.java which is meant to find the ImageView and add an OnClickListener only when BuildConfig.FLAVOR is 'paid'.

When I run the app with the active build variant set to paidDebug, it works as expected, but when I run in freeDebug, it fails to build as it can't find the clickable ImageView. This suggests it is looking in the intended sourceset, but I was hoping the 'if' statement would mean it would only look for the ImageView if BuildConfig.FLAVOR was "paid". If that's not the case, I don't know how to go about this. I tried having different versions of MainActivity.java in the free and paid sourcesets, but got a 'duplicate class' error, and I think this should be possible with an if statement in a single java file.

I'm also getting a highlighted warning on the condition in my code ('"paid".equals(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)' is always true), this whether the active build variant is set to freeDebug or paidDebug, which I don't understand at all. When I print out BuildConfig.FLAVOR, it correctly shows as "paid" in paidDebug and "free" in freeDebug (when I comment out all reference to the ImageView so freeDebug will build and run). So my questions are: Am I going about this the right way? Why does AS think my 'if' statement will always be true? Even when the System.out shows the flavor is 'free', the build process seems to be going into the if statement as if it was true. Thanks if you can help. Code follows:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        System.out.println("BuildConfig.FLAVOR is..."+BuildConfig.FLAVOR);

        if("paid".equals(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)) {

            imageView = findViewById(R.id.clickableImage);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    openPage2Activity();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void openPage2Activity(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Page2Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

from build.gradle(:app)

```
flavorDimensions "paytype"

productFlavors {
    free {
        dimension "paytype"
        applicationIdSuffix ".free"
    }
    paid {
        dimension "paytype"
        applicationIdSuffix ".paid"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

Comment: remove dot (.) .from paid,debug.free

Comment: Thanks @Amit pandey, but not sure what you mean. The only dots I see are in the applicationIdSuffixes.